# ReportViewer page orientation

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting

How can we

1. change Page Orientation to landscape
2. set Reportviewer to Legal Page Size or A4.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this a couple of years back. The 'easiest' way to change orientation was simply change the size. (i.e: portrait A4 is 210 × 297 mm and landscape is 297 x 210 mm)

Comment: can i change it programatically or should i change this in .Rdlc file?

Comment: You should be able to change in code. ( 'PageHeight' and 'PageWidth' properties )

Comment: In properties (right click - report properties) change the page orientation. and resize the report design to 11in width, you can use the ruler (right click - view - ruler) to do it

Answer (score 13):

You can create a PageSettings object, set the properties of that to landscape A4 paper size, and assign that to the Report Viewer instance. For example:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
ps.Landscape = true;
ps.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170);
ps.PaperSize.RawKind = (int)System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4;
reportViewer.SetPageSettings(ps);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using visual studio 2012 you can go to report property, page setup then you can choose the orientation of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Finding that report property was a pain for me because I could not see that "wrench" icon on the reporting bar (which can be open by right clicking on an empty area at the header and clicking "Reports".

Once you get there, change the Orientation to landscape.

Comment: I too had the same problem! I realised that I should click outside the rdlc report border, not on the body or header or footer but outside the report's main border. Then I am able get "Report Properties". Whew!

Comment: that's true... i also realized this after my client wanted to get off from his chair.  hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: In properties (right click - report properties) change the page orientation. 
And resize the report design to 11 inches width, you can use the ruler (right click - view - ruler) to do it